# How to Change View Visibility In Kotlin Callback

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, callback, aws-amplify

I am building an Android application in Kotlin using AWS Amplify for backend. I am attempting to change the visibility of an error message when sign-in fails. I am not super familiar with callbacks/async programming, but my understanding is that the view variable is out of scope when the function gets called. If anyone could understand how to accomplish this I would appreciate it.
Code:

```
binding.login.setOnClickListener(){
    Amplify.Auth.signIn(binding.usernameInput.text.toString() ,binding.passwordInput.text.toString(),
        { result ->
            if (result.isSignInComplete) {
                Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Sign in succeeded")
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
                Log.i("AuthQuickstart", "Sign in not complete")
            }
        },
        {
            Log.e("AuthQuickstart", "Failed to sign in: $it")
            binding.incorrectUsernamePasswordError.visibility = View.VISIBLE //The line that is not working
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Also this is within the onCreate function for the respective activity

Comment: Why is not working? Is just not visible or does the app crash? Have you make sure the callback is the problem? Hardcode the view as visible if it is shown then you narrow down the problem only to the callback, otherwise is something on the layout, after is visible hardcoding the visibility then work on the callback.